# Is it possible to determine that the content of a specific folder has changed, and when it happens, run an ANT task on demand?

Tags: java, ant

In one of my projects the build time is too long. I was able to locate the dependencies, but every time I'm executing a build I have to perform a *clean*, which deletes all the java files and after that the *javac* recompiles everything. This consumes a lot of time.

I'm using ANT for build and I was thinking; is it possible to perform a *clean* (which deletes files) on demand? For the better understanding I made up an example:

- target *top*: builds the *top.jar*
- target *first*: builds the *first.jar*
- target *second*: builds the *second.jar*

*top.jar* depends on *first.jar* and *second.jar*. If I change any files associated to *second.jar*, ANT will run the *second* target, and when this affects the *top.jar*, then ANT will run the *top* target. So far so good.

But, it can happen that I rename a class in *second.jar* - with eclipse for example -, and I end up with two classes: the old class and the new class. Different names, but same content. This can be a problem, that's why I have to run the *clean* target all over the time.

In the example above, I have no problem with running the clean **only** for the target, which has changed.

So my question: **is it possible to determine that the content of a specific folder has changed, and when it happens, run an ANT task on demand?**

I looked around and there is an ANT task with almost the same functionality I need. It is called [depend](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html). Unfortunately it doesn't perform a full delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution to my problem. I'm going to use the [outofdate](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) task of [ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net):

```
<outofdate>
  <sourcefiles path="src3"/>
  <targetfiles path="target/second.jar"/>
  <sequential>
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
      <fileset dir="bin3" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <delete file="target/second.jar"/>
  </sequential>
</outofdate>
<javac .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might [libnotify bindings for java](http://skaba.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/libnotify-java-bindings-adding-actions/) be helpful? If you don't need to run this within java, check out [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), [Kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue), or the like.

Comment: Sorry @Nack, they won't help. I'm a bit confused though. How can a libnotify help in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to switch to an IDE that automatically compiles everything for you in an intelligent way. For example Eclipse compiles every class when it is saved in the editor.

Additionally it is possible to define custom builders (e.g. an ant task) that are executed before or afterwards. That would allow you to automatically update your JAR files using the class files generated by Eclipse from the project's `bin` directory.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Eclipse, because I'm looking for a solution for our continuous integration (hudson + ant)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`<depend>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) in Ant which may do what you want.

Comment: I _tested_ depend, it is almost what I need, but the _former_ class is still there after running it. I may have a look at the source code of depend, and enhance it a bit

Comment: Yeah, depend has no idea what you renamed your class from.